# Set UIImagePickerController Delegate to something other than self

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using a static `UIImagePickerController` that is initialized upon app open to avoid having to waste time, cpu, and memory creating more of them later on.

Because of this, I want to change the `UIImagePickerController`'s delegate . Whenever I try and set the delegate, `print(imagePickerController.delegate)` prints nil, and the delegate is not set.

I have my delegate class like this:

```
class ImagePickerDelegateForProfilePictureController: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
```

And create it using an initializer which provides reference to a profile picture controller like this:

```
MySingletonClass.imagePickerController.delegate = ImagePickerDelegateForProfilePictureController(profilePictureController: self)
```

I have implemented `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` and `imagePickerControllerDidCancel`

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:
Here are the relevant parts of my code. ImagePickerDelegate:

```
// MARK: - ImagePickerDelegateForProfilePictureController
class ImagePickerDelegateForProfilePictureController: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    // The profile picture controller
    var profilePictureController: ProfilePictureController?

    // Initializer for the delegate
    init(profilePictureController: ProfilePictureController) {
        super.init()
        self.profilePictureController = profilePictureController
    }

    // MARK: - Picker Controller Functions
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        // Set profile picture
    }
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        // Dismiss the picker controller
    }
}
```

Relevant code from the ProfilePictureController:

```
lazy var profilePictureDelegate = ImagePickerDelegateForProfilePictureController(profilePictureController: self)

@objc func setDelegateAndPresentImagePicker() {
    // Set the delegate
    MySingletonClass.imagePickerController.delegate = profilePictureDelegate
    // Prints nil
    print(MySingletonClass.imagePickerController.delegate)
    // Present the imagePicker
    present(MySingletonClass.imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

imagePickerController is declared in the singleton class like this

```
// imagePickerController: A standard image picker controller we can change the delegate of
static var imagePickerController: UIImagePickerController {
    let ipc = UIImagePickerController()
    ipc.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]  // import MobileCoreServices, Photos
    return ipc
}
```

Comment: Premature optimization. You are not wasting time, CPU, or memory creating a `UIImagePickerController` each time you need it.

Comment: I see. I have noticed it sometimes takes a few seconds to create and bring up the image picker. Assumed that meant labor. Should I create it in viewDidLoad so it is ready when the user presses choose profile picture button? Want this to run as smooth as possible.

Comment: You can subclass UImagePickerController and set it to be its own delegate